# How to clone part of a List?

Tags: c#, .net, list, clone

Is it possible to clone just part of a `List<T>`?

Example:

```
List<string> myoriginalstring = new List<string>();
myoriginalstring.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
myoriginalstring.Add("Amargasaurus");
myoriginalstring.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
```

I want to clone `myoriginalstring` to another list but just from index `1` to index `2`.

Is that possible? Changes in the second `List<string>` should be reflected in first and vice-versa.

### UPDATE

Thanks for the answers so far. It seems I didn't express myself correctly.

Actually I don't want to copy or clone. I need to create a new list (which will be some part of the original one); and when I change something (some value) in my new list, the original should be also changed the same way. (The lists should be identical all the time, just the new list will be some part of the original).

Hopefully that is clearer.

Comment: Changes should be reflected? In that case, it doesn't sound like you're actually trying to *clone* anything, you just want to wrap one object with another (where the wrapper maybe does some reindexing stuff).

Comment: sounds like ref keyword is the way out

Comment: More specifics about reflected changes would be helpful. If I insert a new element at index 2, how does that affect your sublist of indices 1-2?

Comment: sounds to me like the software design needs to be thought out a little more.

Comment: Permit me to clarify O. R. Mapper's statement: The term "clone" means that changes are *NOT* reflected.  If I clone myself, then my clone changes clothes, my clothes remain the unchanged. :-)

Comment: Are you using LINQ? the answer will lye with `Queryable.ElementAt<TSource>` and encapulating the list in your own object that implements ICollection<T>

Comment: @BrettCaswell: How is anyone supposed to change the list based on an `IQueryable`?

Comment: It might be more helpful to describe, at a higher level, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can't you just loop through the list in a for loop?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `ListSlice<T>` class that represents a slice of an existing list. The slice will behave as a read-only list and because it keeps a reference to the original list you are not supposed to add or remove elements in the original list. This cannot be enforced unless you implement your own list but I will not do that here.

You will have to implement the entire `IList<T>` interface including the `IEnumerator<T>` you need for enumerating the slice. Here is an example:

```
class ListSlice<T> : IList<T> {

  readonly IList<T> list;

  readonly Int32 startIndex;

  readonly Int32 length;

  public ListSlice(IList<T> list, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) {
    if (list == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    if (!(0 <= startIndex && startIndex < list.Count))
      throw new ArgumentException("startIndex");
    if (!(0 <= length && length <= list.Count - startIndex))
      throw new ArgumentException("length");

    this.list = list;
    this.startIndex = startIndex;
    this.length = length;
  }

  public T this[Int32 index] {
    get {
      if (!(0 <= index && index < this.length))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      return this.list[this.startIndex + index];
    }
    set {
      if (!(0 <= index && index < this.length))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
      this.list[this.startIndex + index] = value;
    }
  }

  public Int32 IndexOf(T item) {
    var index = this.list.IndexOf(item);
    return index == -1 || index >= this.startIndex + this.length
      ? -1 : index - this.startIndex;
  }

  public void Insert(Int32 index, T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

  public void RemoveAt(Int32 index) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

  public Int32 Count { get { return this.length; } }

  public Boolean IsReadOnly { get { return true; } }

  public void Add(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

  public void Clear() { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

  public Boolean Contains(T item) { return IndexOf(item) != -1; }

  public void CopyTo(T[] array, Int32 arrayIndex) {
    for (var i = this.startIndex; i < this.length; i += 1)
      array[i + arrayIndex] = this.list[i];
  }

  public Boolean Remove(T item) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return new Enumerator(this.list, this.startIndex, this.length);
  }

  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }

  class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T> {

    readonly IList<T> list;

    readonly Int32 startIndex;

    readonly Int32 length;

    Int32 index;

    T current;

    public Enumerator(IList<T> list, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) {
      this.list = list;
      this.startIndex = startIndex;
      this.length = length;
    }

    public T Current { get { return this.current; } }

    Object IEnumerator.Current {
      get {
        if (this.index == 0 || this.index == this.length + 1)
          throw new InvalidOperationException();
        return Current;
      }
    }

    public Boolean MoveNext() {
      if (this.index < this.length) {
        this.current = this.list[this.index + this.startIndex];
        this.index += 1;
        return true;
      }
      this.current = default(T);
      return false;
    }

    public void Reset() {
      this.index = 0;
      this.current = default(T);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
    }

  }

}
```

You can write an extension method to make it easier to work with slices:

```
static class ListExtensions {

  public static ListSlice<T> Slice<T>(this IList<T> list, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) {
    return new ListSlice<T>(list, startIndex, length);
  }

}
```

To use the slice you can write code like this:

```
var list = new List<String> {
  "Tyrannosaurus",
  "Amargasaurus",
  "Mamenchisaurus"
};
var slice = list.Slice(1, 2);
slice[0] = "Stegosaurus";
```

Now `list[1]` as well as `slice[0]` contains `"Stegosaurus"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is definetly going the direction i need. M.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really did mean clone and not copy...

```
    List<string> myoriginalstring = new List<string> { "Tyrannosaurus", "Amargasaurus", "Mamenchisaurus" };
    List<string> myCloneString = myoriginalstring.GetRange(1, myoriginalstring.Count() -1 );
```

Comment: GetRange method by definition returns a copy. Even with that aside, not sure what "you really did mean clone and not copy" means here.

Comment: Sorry, "... and not a reference to the original".

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. It seems i didnt express myself correctly. Actually i dont want copy or clone, i need to create new list (which will be some part of original list) and when i change something (some value) in my new list the original should be also changed the same way. (The lists should be all the time identical, just the new list will be some part of the original). I hope its clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the first glance, it seems as if

```
var list2 = myoriginalstring.SkipWhile((str, i)=>!(i>=1 && i<=2)).ToList();
list2[1]="Stegosaurus";
```

would be the solution. But it is not, because `list2` is a independent list which contains its own elements. The code above works, but it replaces only the element in the (new) `list2`, not in `myoriginalstring`.

As you pointed out, this is not what you wanted to do.

---

**Solution**

Unlike other languages like C, you don't have access to pointers directly in C#.
Hence, the solution is more complex. Instead of using strings directly, you need to create an object, like the following:

```
public class Dino
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public object[] Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentIndex;
}
```

Then, create some helper extension methods, like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Dino AsDino(this string name)
    {
        return new Dino() {Value=name};
    }
    public static Dino AsDino(this string name, object[] reference, int parentIndex)
    {
        return new Dino() {Value=name, Parent=reference, ParentIndex=parentIndex };
    }
    public static Dino Replace(this object item, Dino replacementItem)
    {
        replacementItem.ParentIndex=((Dino)item).ParentIndex;
        replacementItem.Parent=((Dino)item).Parent;
        ((Dino)item).Parent[replacementItem.ParentIndex]=replacementItem;
        return replacementItem;
    }
}
```

With those helpers, you can do it:

```
// create array with 3 elements
var myoriginalstring = new object[3];

// fill in the dinosours and keep track of the array object and positions within
myoriginalstring[0]="Tyrannosaurus".AsDino(myoriginalstring, 0); 
myoriginalstring[1]="Amargasaurus".AsDino(myoriginalstring, 1); 
myoriginalstring[2]="Mamenchisaurus".AsDino(myoriginalstring, 2); 

// get a subset of the array
var list2 = myoriginalstring.SkipWhile((str, i)=>!(i>=1 && i<=2)).ToList<object>();

// replace the value at index 1 in list2. This will also replace the value
//  in the original array myoriginalstring 
list2[1].Replace("Stegosaurus".AsDino());
```

The trick is, that the `Dino` class keeps track of its origin (the array `myoriginalstring`) and the position within it (i.e. its index).